# How to gradually increase scale using scale3d while scrolling the page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to gradually increase scale using scale3d on css while scrolling the page. Like from

```
scale3d(1, 1, 1) to scale3d(2, 2, 2)
```

```
const container       = document.querySelector('.container-testi');
const containerHeight = container.scrollHeight;
const iWillExpand     = document.querySelector('.iWillExpand');
   
container.onscroll = function(e) {
   iWillExpand.style.transform = `scale3d(${0.8 + 0.2 * container.scrollTop / (containerHeight - 
   300)})`;
    };
```

```
.iWillExpand{
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) 
      rotateX( 0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); 
      transform-style: preserve-3d; 
      }
```

My code isn't working the way I wanted, is there any way I can do it? thank you

Comment: where is the CSS ?

Comment: This is my css
.iWillExpand{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(
0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

Comment: not in the comment, update your question

Comment: Done, sorry I am newbie here

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.scrollY` property and sum it with the `transform: scale3d()` property using javascript. Below is a rudimentary example of how it can be done.

```js
const display = document.querySelector('.display')
display.style.position = 'fixed';

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let value = window.scrollY
  let box = document.querySelector('.box')
  let num1 = (1 + value * .002).toFixed(2)
  let num2 = (1 + value * .001).toFixed(2)
  let num3 = (1 + value * .005).toFixed(2)
  box.style.transform = `scale3d(${num1}, ${num2}, ${num3})`
  
  display.textContent = `First scale value: ${num1}, Second scale value: ${num2}, Third scale value: ${num3}`
})
```

```css
#main {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="display"></div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

that should do it ...
using css variables is easier

```css
:root {
  --sXYZ  : 1;
  }
.iWillExpand {
  transform : translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) 
              scale3d( var(--sXYZ), var(--sXYZ), var(--sXYZ) ) 
              rotateX( 0deg) 
              rotateY(0deg) 
              rotateZ(0deg) 
              skew(0deg, 0deg)
              ; 
  transform-style : preserve-3d; 
  }
```

```js
const 
  Root            = document.documentElement
, container       = document.querySelector('.container-testi') 
, containerHeight = container.scrollHeight
  ;
container.onscroll = () =>
  {
  let calc = 0.8  + 0.2 * container.scrollTop / (containerHeight - 300)
  Root.style.setProperty('--sXYZ', calc)
  }
```